# Why are my PyQt Widgets overlapping?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

```
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
    self.setWindowTitle("test")

    self.createActions()

    self.mainWidget=QWidget(self)
    self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)

    self.createListView()
    self.lv.setMinimumSize(200,200)

    self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
    self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(200,200)

    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.lv)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
```

All this does is creates a window with a toolbar and puts two widgets inside a QHBoxLayout, a QListView and a QTextEdit. Yet for some reason all three things appear to overlap. (Toolbar visible underneath the widgets)

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put those widgets and layouts in **the central widget** of your `QMainWindow`. Here is the composition of a `QMainWindow`:

[image]

<sub>(Picture from PyQt document: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget )</sub>

In your case, the solution is to set the `QHBoxLayout` as your central widget's layout:

`self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)`

(There is no need to create another `QWidget` to hold it, you may just exploit the existing central widget.)

Answer (score 3):

`QMainWindow` already has a layout which handles things like menu bars and status bars. It also has a central widget for adding your own layout to. As such, if you add the line of code `self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)` then your existing widget with layout (`mainLayout`) will be placed in the layout build into `QMainWindow`.

Your current code just says your widget (`mainWidget`) is a child of the main window. It doesn't say where to put it, or how to lay it out. So Qt just dumps it at coordinates (0,0) of the parent specified.